# Visual Studio 2017 with Apache Cordova (install android emulator)

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2017

I recently try on Apache Cordova with Visual Studio 2017, but failed to debug with Android SDK, I was follow the step post by [Open Google Emulator in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302325/how-to-open-google-android-emulator-in-visual-studio-2017). It was show me to "Install Android Emulators", but I follow to install but it was repeat to ask me the same thing. [Install Android Emulators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N39AC.jpg). It was ask me to install "Google Android Emulator API Level 23.

Below was my setting:

1. Tool for Apache Cordova-Environment Variable Overrides-ANDROID_HOME:C:\Users\yeech\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
2. Google Android Emulator file location: C:\Users\yeech\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a known issue (at least for me) with VS2017 and another reason to keep using VS2015 instead. For more details check out this article: [Visual Studio 2017 and Apache Cordova mobile apps](https://www.andreszsogon.com/visual-studio-2017-and-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/)

> To compile for Android with Cordova 7.1.0, you may need to switch to
>   the Android SDK API 26 by changing the ANDROID_HOME setting from
>   Visual Studio. This introduces the problem that your Android emulators
>   are no longer detected and you cannot deploy to emulator.

As explained in the page, your only workaround is to manually deploy using the CLI, a total pain that can be avoided by returning to VS2015.

Comment: Thank you, look like only using VS2015 can help me. VS2017 really cause a lot problem. After I reinstall the API 23, then able to launch the debug but is with API 23 only. After another day, I totally cannot debug again but it was the same debug. =.="